# Can't make calculations using a mix of TextView and EditText

Tags: android

I'm currently making a very simple math game. In this math game I want the player to solve easy equations. It looks like this: 9 * __ = 45, the player then fill in the correct number to solve the equation and then presses a Correct-button. If correct scores are added to the player.

The empty space is an EditText and the others are TextViews. Because I use a mix of TextView & EditText I need somehow to make a convertion for the program to be able to read and calculate. I've been reading like crazy and tried all kinds of different methods without success. How should I do to get around this?

This is how my data looks like:

**activity_play.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_play"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.android.laboration2.PlayActivity">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPlayMultiply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textPlayNumber1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/multiply"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_gravity = "start"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPlayNumber1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textPlayScore"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textPlayScore"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:text="@string/number_1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPlayEqual"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/equal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPlayNumber2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textPlayMultiply"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textPlayMultiply" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPlayResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:text="@string/result_number3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textPlayEqual"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textPlayEqual"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textPlayEqual" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPlayScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/answerButton"
            android:text="@string/score_0"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/answerButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answerButton"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:text="@string/button_result"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textPlayResult"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPlayNumber2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textPlayMultiply"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textPlayMultiply"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/answerButton"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/answerButton"
            android:hint="    "
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPlayLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textPlayScore"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textPlayScore"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/answerButton"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/answerButton"
            android:text="@string/level_0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

.

**PlayActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.laboration2;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


        TextView textPlayNumber1;
        EditText editTextPlayNumber2;
        TextView textPlayResult;
        TextView textPlayScore;
        TextView textPlayLevel;
        Button answerButton;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

            textPlayNumber1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPlayNumber1);
            editTextPlayNumber2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayNumber2);
            textPlayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPlayResult);
            textPlayScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPlayScore);
            textPlayLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPlayLevel);

            answerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerButton);
            answerButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }//onCreate ends here


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }//onClick ends here


    }//PlayActivity ends here
```

Comment: how are you saying that can't mix them? you're not even showing your calculation codes.

Comment: I haven't showed because what ever I've tried it simply hasn't worked because it always complained that the TextView uses an Int while the EditText was a String. So I have erased everything, hopeing someone to tell me a way of how to set up calculations. Any suggestions?

Comment: then post your code, we can't just simply assume, both should work technically if you're pulling the right values of those elements and parsing them correctly

Comment: How can be the TextView value is a Int ? Please explain. It is showing an Integer but actual value it is a string.

Comment: Just me being an total confused beginner! Been working with android for approx. 1 month only (just partly when I had time). So I still got loads to learn. My apologize for the confusion of the terms etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TextView and EditText all have String type values. You have to parse those value to Integer then calculate and show the result.

Here is the action onClick answer button-

```
 int score = 0;
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()){
           case R.id.answerButton:
                int playNum1 = Integer.parseInt(textPlayNumber1.getText().toString());
                int playNum2 = Integer.parseInt(editTextPlayNumber2.getText().toString());
                int playResult = Integer.parseInt(textPlayResult.getText().toString());
                if(playNum1*playNum2 == playResult){
                    score++;
                    textPlayScore.setText(""+score);
                 }                     
            break;
       }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped me BIG TIME! Can't thank you enough! My problem was that I thought I needed to convert one of these, therefore I got errors all the time. Like you did above I just needed to parse them into integers since both were strings. I always mistaked the EditText probably for an int because only numbers can be written there. Read something about it in earlier posts.

Comment: You are welcome. I understood what got you confused here. You set your EditText input type to Number. This only affects the soft input method (keyboard) for user's convenience. But the value you get is always a string. You may read about it here : https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Comment: Honestly, the Android Developers site is terrible. I think they need to re-write everything or make an easy to understand version for beginners. I hardly get anything when they explain how to use the different codes in combination with others and what they actually do. Once again, thank you so much! This has been killing me for daaaays! Spending 6h/day reading and coding, reading and coding.
I got enough and decided to make my own account. Now I feel like an idiot for not have done it earlier. The help came literally in minutes and the acitivity is great!

Comment: could you help me out with another issue of mine? How to store high score? I'm doing an simple math app where I want to store the high score in another Activity. Using the codes above how do I go around to store my score and display it in a High Score textview in another activity?

Comment: Do you want to just pass it to another activity or save the data even app is being killed?

Comment: No I'd like the data to be saved.

Comment: Then you may Use SharedPreference. It will keep the data until you uninstall app/clear app data.

Comment: I don't know how. I've tried it before and it was and still are a pain in the ass to get to work. Taking the coding in consideration, could you guide me with a code how to write it for this specific math game app?

Comment: Sure, but you have to ask a separate question. There is no room for another answer.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I wanted at first to send you a private message asking about it, but apparantely it's not possible. I'll make a separate question then.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
int playNumberValue = Integer.getInteger(textPlayNumber1.getText().toString());
int userInputValue = Integer.getInteger(editTextPlayNumber2.getText().toString());
int result = Integer.getInteger(textPlayResult.getText().toString());

if(result == userInputValue+playNumberValue)
    //win game
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Really appreciate it. However, the post above is exacly what I wanted to use.